# redux-presist not updating local storage a browser

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, redux-persist

I'm using redux-persist for my e-commerce project.

When I updated my app to new version I found a new bug.

I changed my initialState from array into object.

My app in Chrome (browser that i test and run my app on it) crashed !! because my initialState still array(NOT UPDATE) and new method was not returned anything. (Of course).

But in Mozilla and other Browsers that I not use before them my app working currently !

**why!?**

My Store Config :

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import logger from 'redux-logger'

import RootReducer from './RootReducer'

const middleware = [logger]

export const store = createStore(RootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middleware))

export const persistore = persistStore(store)
```

My rootReducer Config :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

import UserReducer from './User/UserReducer'
import ShoppingBagDropdownReducer from './ShoppingBagDropdown/ShoppingBagDropdownReducer'
import DirectoryReducer from './Directory/DirectoryReducer'
import ShopDataReducer from './ShopData/ShopDataReducer'

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    whileList: ['shoppingBagDropdown']
}


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: UserReducer,
    shoppingBagDropdown: ShoppingBagDropdownReducer,
    shopData: ShopDataReducer,
    directory: DirectoryReducer
})

export default persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah :)

I found solution and that is : clear local storage with :

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you fixed it, but you could also do it without code using google chrome.

```
CTRL + SHIFT + I > Application > Local Storage
```

Now you just have to open the localstorage, right click and click on clear.